# How to get ConEmu tab index from command line?

Tags: conemu

I am writing script to setup environment variable based on tab index. eg.
if tab 1 cd /d c:\proj1
if tab 2 cd /d c:\proj2
etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no sense to check the tab index or name - they may be changed in runtime by user at any time.

I recommend you to set some yours environment variable in the task to distinguish started consoles. E.g.:

```
set MyTabID=tab1 & cmd /k your-command-1
set MyTabID=tab2 & cmd /k your-command-2
```

Comment: Yes, I end up with:
ConEmu /Reuse /run "%ComSpec% /k myscript.cmd c:\proj1"
ConEmu /Reuse /run "%ComSpec% /k myscript.cmd c:\proj2"